# Simple search in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to do a pretty simple search. I have a `search` action in my controller:

```
def search
      @tracker = Tracker.where(params[:search])
  end
```

And, in my view:

```
<%= form_tag trackers_search_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

But, it's still returning nil values. Here's the log:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "id"=>"search", "search"=>"1Xc9fc0e"}
  Tracker Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "trackers".* FROM "trackers" WHERE ("trackers"."token" = 'search') LIMIT 1
```

Seems to me, it's not passing the right `param` into the select statement, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: I should mention I did try `Tracker.where(:token => params[:search])` already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the routing might be messed up? Are you sure the `search` action is actually being called? It looks like it's going to `show` with id `search`. Try adding a `debugger` call or a `Rails.logger.debug` call to see what action is being called. Or just look at the entire log entry.

Comment: Good call!  That didn't even occur to me, but makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I started to figure out. This is my route: `match "trackers/search" => 'trackers#index'` so I can't figure out how it's getting to `show`

Comment: try putting that before `resources :trackers`, routes match top down picking the first match so if it sees `/trackers/search` it'll match on `trackers#show` first.